# Auto-filing Formula to Last Row of a Single Column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to constantly start at cell R2 and auto-fill a formula down to the last row of column R. However, the number of rows is constantly changing so I need to write a macro that finds the last row and stops their.  I've tried this code but keep getting errors.  Any thoughts?

```
Sub InvoicePrice()

Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("R2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-4]"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2" & Lastrow)
```

Comment: What error and on what line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to this `Range("R2" & Lastrow)`

The range address concatenates to `R21400` if the last row was 1400.  So we need to add the `:R` to the address.

```
Range("R2:R" & Lastrow)
```

It will now concatenate to `R2:R1400`

There is not need to do it with three lines, one will suffice:

```
Sub InvoicePrice()

Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("R2:R" & Lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-4]"

End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate the quick reply Scott.  This code only entered the formula in cells R1 and R2 however.  It did not auto-fill down the entire column.

Comment: Then R only has values to row 2 when you run it.  You will need to choose a different column to find the last row.

Comment: R has 57 values in it in this particular instance.  Even if I change "R2" to "R2:R" on the last line of my original code I still get the error

Comment: I changed my original code to have the range you suggested which worked.  I realized that xlUp needed to change to xlDown, and find the last row in column P not R.  But now my code will not stop where my data stops, any thoughts?

Comment: If you're filling the column R, should you search for the last row in a column that has filled with data, shouldnt it? @oryan5000

Comment: If the data is in column P, the line code should be: `Lastrow = Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @rafeael Yes I changed the code to reference column P but I'm still getting the problem that the formula continues to the bottom of the sheet and not were the data in column P stops

Comment: @oryan5000 put a break on the last line, then see what LastRow is.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already tried this:

```
Sub InvoicePrice()

Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("P2").End(xlDown).Row

Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-4]"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2" & Lastrow)
```

It seems to me that `Range("R" & Rows.Count)` locates you out of current region